# How to creat cpp files in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am working with "eclips" for  C++ programming  but I dont know how to make a .cpp or .c file in this software. In elder soft wares doing it was very simple: 
New / cpp file and end but in "eclips" is very hard and confused me. Thanks for coperations.

Comment: WTH is _"eclips"_?? Did you actually mean _Eclipse CDT_?

Comment: `File->New->Other->C/C++->Source File`

Answer (score 4):

Try right-clicking on the project file explorer on the right side and selecting New->File. Name your file and add .cpp to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

In (JUNO) Eclipse you can easily do this.

**Right click on Package Explorer --> New Project --> Select C/C++ Project**. All class/files derived from that project should be in .cpp file.